# aspect(perfective or imperfective)

Tags: aspect

In CGEL page no.126 "I already knew how to do it."[Tr included within Tsit]..., if Tr is internal part within Tsit so this shows imperfective aspect.., is this right or wrong? And also 1) I knew how to do it and 2) I already knew how to do it. Is any difference in these aspect sentences with or without adverb "already"?

Comment: This question is almost identical to your questions 288989 and 289046.  I gave you an answer to the latter.  Was that not sufficient?